# Is it possible to set alarm programmatically in Android wear smart watch?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have to create an application for Android Wear which schedules a task in background.For this I have used `AlarmManager` in wearable app. But after this my application is not listed in Wearable emulator.

Is it possible to schedule tasks using Alarm Manager in wearable itself?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html

*"For apps that require more frequent updates, such as a fitness, time-keeping, and travel information apps, use an AlarmManager object to wake the processor and update the screen more frequently."*